# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3 Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

I am trying to apply a where clause my script is like

```
set ansi_nulls off

select
    Name, Count(Distinct [Document Name])
from 
    dbo.timeless
where 
    origin in ('2', 'I', 'E')
    and [svs check] IN ('0', '.', 'NO', 'OK', '#N/A')
```

Then I get the error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
>   Error converting data type varchar to float

When I comment out `[svs check]`, everything goes fine. So the problem is in `[svs check]`. Kindly help.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field  [svs check]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `dbo.timeless.svscheck` is of type float and you can't compare it with string literals.

I suggest casting that to varchar first using `CAST(svs as VARCHAR(10))` although I doubt that your where clause will work if it is really float, as you're checking it against string literals.